# Balancing redox reaction by removing spectator ion SO₄²¯

Tags: redox

I aimed to balance the equation

$$ \ce{Cr2O^{2-}_7 + FeSO4 + H+ -> Cr^{3+} + Fe2(SO4)3} $$

My teacher explained me that since $\ce{SO^{2-}_4}$ is the spectator ion, I must proceed in this equation like this:

$$\ce{ Cr2O^{2-}_7  + Fe^{2+} + H+ -> Cr^{3+} + Fe^{3+} },$$

i.e by removing $\ce{SO^{2-}_4}$ ions.

After balancing,

$$\ce{6 Fe^{2+} + Cr2O^{2-}_7 + 14 H+ -> 6 Fe^{3+} + 2 Cr^{3+} + 7 H2O}$$

Now she asked me to add $\ce{7 SO^{2-}_4}$ to the left hand side of the equation; and $\ce{9 SO^{2-}_4}$, $\ce{3 SO^{2-}_4}$ and $\ce{1 SO^{2-}_4}$ to the right hand side.

Then the equation becomes:

$$\ce{6Fe^{2+} + 6 SO^{2-}_4 + Cr2O^{2-}_7 + 14 H+ +7 SO^{2-}_4 ->  6 Fe^{3+} + 9 SO^{2-}_4  + 2 Cr^{3+} + 7 H2O + SO^{2-}_4} $$

Which becomes:

$$\ce{6 FeSO4 + Cr2O^{2-}_7 +7 H2SO4 -> 3 Fe2(SO4)3 + Cr2(SO4)3 + 7 H2O + SO^{2-}_4}$$

Is it the correct procedure for balancing redox reactions?

Comment: There are many correct procedures. You may balance with $\ce{SO4^2-}$, or you may balance without it. In the end it is all the same.

Comment: Procedures leading to balanced reaction equations are correct ones. The others are incorrect. So a better question is, if it is an optimal or effective procedure. // What  makes the task little weird is being a hybrid of a complete "molecular" approach and of the ionic approach, omitting all spectator ions/molecules. Generaly, the fully ionic approach is more effective, as there is less things to balance. When done, if needed, bystanders can be added rather mechanically.

Comment: Instead of the direct text formatting, you may consider as useful   [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and [How can I format math expressions or chem. equations on Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here). // 6Fe²﹢ + Cr₂O7²¯ +14H﹢ → 6Fe³﹢ + 2Cr³﹢ +7H₂O  versus  `$\ce{6 Fe^2+ + Cr2O7^2-  + 14 H+ -> 6 Fe^3+ + 2 Cr^3+  + 7 H2O}$` : $\ce{6 Fe^2+ + Cr2O7^2-  + 14 H+ -> 6 Fe^3+ + 2 Cr^3+  + 7 H2O}$

Comment: @Poutnik I was wondering if $\ce{SO4^2-}$ is truly a spectator ion in this equation.

Comment: @MsBonniePython Nothing happens to $\ce{SO4^2}$ during the reaction, since the beginning till the very end. Remember that writing  $\ce{FeSO4}$ or $\ce{Fe2(SO4)3}$  in context of water solutions is very formal. As salts, strong acids and strong bases exist in solution as independent ions. There are $\ce{Fe^2+}$, $\ce{Fe^3+}$ and $\ce{SO4^2}$.

Comment: Take the time during one of the following days to familiarize yourself with the examples  [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) provides.  It is helpful to use this extension for the body of questions, answers, and comments here on chemistry.se when formatting such equations.  Don't use it in the title of questions (because it is special and not understood by all browsers).

Answer (score 1):

Balancing a reaction equation is a sequential process.  One approach is that

- you identify the starting materials by their formulae, and the reaction products by theirs.
- you balance the equation such the same number of atoms on the left hand side equates the number of atoms on the left hand side.

  Depending on the reaction, there are some groups of atoms, or ions (e.g., $\ce{SO^{2-}_4}$) which possibly stay intact *as such*. If so, you may count sulfate ions, too.  But this is risky, as ions consisting of multiple atoms may be transformed, too.  E.g., the dichromate ion:

  $$\ce{Cr2O^{2-}_7 + 14 H3O+ + 6e- -> 2 Cr^{3+} + 21 H2O  } $$

  or the sulfate ion:

  $$\ce{2 SO^{2-}_4 -> S2O^{2-}_8 + 2 e-} $$
- you equally balance the total of charges on the left with the total of charges on the right hand side.  In the case of redox reactions, there are a few reactions where molecules of water are on the side of starting materials, or the one of reaction products.  These may help to balance charges and atoms, too.  Note, these should match with the reaction conditions, too; the above about the dichromate for example (many equivalents $\ce{H3O+}$) is in agreement that this reaction is more likely to happen in acidic media (high concentration  of hydronium ions), than in neuter or basic solution.

In some cases, it is necessary to repeat the second and third step a couple of times.

Re spectators: It may happen that you have ions/molecules both on the left, as well as on the right hand side of the arrow.  Say, for a hypothetical reaction you reach

$$\ce{5 H2O + \text{starting materials} -> 3 H2O + \text{products}}$$

which may be simplified to

$$\ce{2 H2O + \text{starting materials} -> \text{products}}$$

*if* the second equation still is balanced in the number of atoms on the left and right hand side, *and* equally is balanced for the total of charges on the left/on the right hand side.  The simplification, e.g.,

$$\ce{2 H2O + \text{starting materials} -> 2 H2O \text{products}}$$

into

$$\ce{\text{starting materials} -> \text{products}}$$

including the labeling «here, water molecules are mere bystanders of the reaction» requires that you know the reaction (with set conditions, is it possible that water/sulfate ions/iron ions react?) by observation, or (better: *and*) that you recognize in the balanced reaction equation that these neither are formed, nor consumed.  This however only is a necessary condition, not an always sufficient one about a spectator: overall, ideal *catalysts* of a reaction are neither formed, nor consumed either; yet in many instances a requirement to increase the rate of a reaction (e.g., the generation of ammonia from hydrogen and nitrogen by the Bosch process).